# Stuck on a subquery that is grouping, in Linq`

Tags: linq

I have some Linq code and it's working fine. It's a query that has a subquery in the `Where` clause. This subquery is doing a groupby. Works great.

The problem is that I don't know how to grab one of the results from the subquery out of the subquery into the parent.

Frst, here's the code. After that, I'll expplain what piece of data i'm wanting to extract.

```
    var results = (from a in db.tblProducts
               where (from r in db.tblReviews
                      where r.IdUserModified == 1
                      group r by
                          new
                              {
                                  r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Alpha,
                                  r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Beta,
                                  r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Gamma
                              }
                      into productGroup
                          orderby productGroup.Count() descending
                          select
                          new
                              {
                                  productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Alpha,
                                  productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Beta,
                                  productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Gamma,
                                  ReviewCount = productGroup.Count()
                              }).Take(3)
                   .Any(
                   r =>
                   r.IdProductCode_Alpha== a.IdProductCode_Alpha&& 
                       r.IdProductCode_Beta== a.IdProductCode_Beta&&
                       r.IdProductCode_Gamma== a.IdProductCode_Gamma)
               where a.ProductFirstName == ""
               select new {a.IdProduct, a.FullName}).ToList();
```

Ok. I've changed some field and tables names to protect the innocent. :)

See this last line :-

```
select new {a.IdProduct, a.FullName}).ToList();
```

I wish to include in that the ReviewCount (from the subquery). I'm jus not sure how.

To help understand the problem, this is what the data looks like.

#### Sub Query

IdProductCode_Alpha = 1, IdProductCode_Beta = 2, IdProductCode_Gamma = 3, ReviewCount = 10
... row 2 ...
... row 3 ...

#### Parent Query

IdProduct = 69, FullName = 'Jon Skeet's Wonder Balm'

So the subquery grabs the actual data i need. The parent query determines the correct product, based on the subquery filters.

## EDIT 1: Schema

tblProducts

- IdProductCode
- FullName
- ProductFirstName

tblReviews (each product has zero to many reviews)

- IdProduct
- IdProductCode_Alpha (can be null)
- IdProductCode_Beta (can be null)
- IdProductCode_Gamma (can be null)
- IdPerson

So i'm trying to find the top 3 products a person has done reviews on.

The linq works perfectly... except i just don't know how to include the COUNT in the parent query (ie. pull that result from the subquery).

Cheers :)

Comment: I suppose it will be better to have the schema alongwith sample data & expected output will help people form the query.

Comment: I guess the schema is incomplete. What do you mean by person? How would you write SQL if it were a database?

Comment: yeah. it's way incomplete cause it's all pseduo code and i'm trying to do this on the fly. I'm not allowed to post any real code to the public domain (contracts, etc. etc.. ) i know i know :(

Comment: I've now ammended the schema a wee bit by adding in a Person to the review table. Each review is posted by a human. Each product can have zero to many reviews posted against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it myself. Take note of the double `from` at the start of the query, then the `Any`() being replaced by a `Where()` clause.

```
var results = (from a in db.tblProducts
               from g in (
                  from r in db.tblReviews
                  where r.IdUserModified == 1
                  group r by
                      new
                          {
                              r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Alpha,
                              r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Beta,
                              r.tblAddress.IdProductCode_Gamma
                          }
                  into productGroup
                      orderby productGroup.Count() descending
                      select
                      new
                          {
                              productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Alpha,
                              productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Beta,
                              productGroup.Key.IdProductCode_Gamma,
                              ReviewCount = productGroup.Count()
                          })
                  .Take(3)
           Where(g.IdProductCode_Alpha== a.IdProductCode_Alpha&& 
               g.IdProductCode_Beta== a.IdProductCode_Beta&&
               g.IdProductCode_Gamma== a.IdProductCode_Gamma)
           where a.ProductFirstName == ""
           select new {a.IdProduct, a.FullName, g.ReviewCount}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

While I don't understand LINQ completely, but wouldn't the JOIN work?
I know my answer doesn't help but it looks like you need a JOIN with the inner table(?).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with shahkalpesh, both about the schema and the join.

You should be able to refactor...

```
 r => r.IdProductCode_Alpha == a.IdProductCode_Alpha  && 
      r.IdProductCode_Beta == a.IdProductCode_Beta  &&
      r.IdProductCode_Gamma == a.IdProductCode_Gamma
```

into an inner join with `tblProducts`.