# Linq subquery - with take

Tags: linq, subquery, grouping

Working on a problem where I have a set of data related to horse racing. Like here:

```
        outingsData = new List<RPOutingFull>();
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 1, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(-5) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 2, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(-4) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 99, HorseID = 2, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(-4) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 3, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = 3, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(-1) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 4, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = 3, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+1) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 5, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = 6, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+4) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 6, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+5) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 7, HorseID = hid1, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+22) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 8, HorseID = 3, FinishPositionVal = winPos, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+22) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 9, HorseID = 5, FinishPositionVal = 2, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+27) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 10, HorseID = 5, FinishPositionVal = 4, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+55) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 11, HorseID = 5, FinishPositionVal = 4, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+56) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 12, HorseID = 5, FinishPositionVal = 5, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+95) });
        outingsData.Add(new RPOutingFull() { ID = 13, HorseID = 5, FinishPositionVal = 6, theDate = outingsStartDate.AddDays(+96) });
```

I want to write a linq query - that provides a predicate to select an initial item in the data, and then return the subsequent x records for EACH qualifying horse

An example; given this data, and the predicate of the initial item having FinishPositionVal = 3, and taking 2 of the subsequent outings for all matching runners... should return items with IDs 4,5,6

```
        // take next 2 outings
        int takeCount = 2;
        Predicate<RPOutingFull> predicate = full => full.FinishPositionVal == 3;

        var resAllSubsequentOutings = (from s1 in outingsData
                   from s2 in outingsData
                   where
                    s2.theDate > s1.theDate && s1.HorseID == s2.HorseID &&
                    predicate(s1)
                    orderby s1.theDate
                   select s2);
```

This part returns all subsequent outings where the initial predicate matches. I could group this return set, and take top x from each runner.. but thats not correct. Because..... the predicate has independently started from two separate points in the data: from ID 3, 4 (where position = 3), so the take should be for 2 subsequent outings from each point ... ie ID 4,5 should be picked up due to ID3 matching predicate, and ID5,6 picked up due to ID4 matching predicate... then 4,5,5,6 distinct should leave with 4,5,6....

```
        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<long>() { 4, 5, 6 }, resMissingQuery.Select(o => o.ID));
```

Thanks

Comment: Found a solution to this after adapting query from: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880665/stuck-on-a-subquery-that-is-grouping-in-linq

Comment: Solution:          var q = (from s1 in outingsData
                from g in (
                    from s2 in outingsData
                    where
                        s2.theDate > s1.theDate && s1.HorseID == s2.HorseID &&
                        predicate(s1)
                    orderby s1.theDate
                    select s2).Take(takeCount)

                select g).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: I am trying to re-write this as a join query to improve performance.... thats not so easy. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried for the join query and where your problem is exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

For Matt Ko, the join query I've come up with is:

```
        Predicate<RPOutingWithNoComment> predicate = r => r.FinishPositionVal == 3; 
        var res = (from s1 in _testData
                   join s2 in _testData on s1.HorseID equals s2.HorseID
                   where s2.theDate > s1.theDate &&
                       s1.HorseID == s2.HorseID && predicate(s1)
                   orderby s2.theDate
                   select s2).Distinct();
```

This works on getting subsequent runs, now I want to restrict the result set to take only 2 of the subsequent runs AFTER the initial run predicate selects the run. I know, to get ONLY the next run after the qualifying run, I can use:

```
        var q = from r in res
            group r by r.HorseID
            into g
            select g.OrderBy(o => o.theDate).First();
```